# Getting mom sponsored through her brother for Schengen

Tags: visa, germany, schengen, blue-card

I am in Germany with a 1 year contract which is ending in March. I have been promised an extension but it may take a couple of more months. But I thought of bringing my mom to Germany on schengen visa through her brother who is also here. Because I will be going to Sri Lanka this December and I can bring her with me when I come back. This will not be possible if I wait for my extension and then get a longer visa and then sponsor her as I only have 5 weeks to go before I leave for Sri Lanka on vacation.

So if he sponsors her, while I'm here, will that be problematic for her in getting the visa? I'm super confused, any help will be much appreciated.